# How to deploy a verticle on a Web server/Application server?

Tags: vert.x

I'm just beginning to learn Vert.x and how to code Verticles. I wonder if it makes any sense to deploy a Verticle from within an Application server or Web server like Tomcat. For example:

```
public class HelloVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloVerticle.class);
  private long counter = 1;

  @Override
  public void start() {
    vertx.setPeriodic(5000, id -> {
      logger.info("tick");
    });

    vertx.createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler(req -> {
        logger.info("Request #{} from {}", counter++, req.remoteAddress().host());
        req.response().end("Hello!");
      })
      .listen(9080);
    logger.info("Open http://localhost:9080/");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(new HelloVerticle());
  }
}
```

Obviously the main method needs to be replaced by some ContextListener of any trigger provided by the Application Server. Does it make any sense or it's not supposed to use Vert.x in this Context?
Thanks

Comment: Tomcat is a web container. Vert.x has an embedded web server. While technically it's possible, I cannot imagine what benefits are you expecting to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vert.x as a Verticle inside a Tomcat app doesn't make much sense from my POV, because it defeats the whole point of componentization.

On the other hand you might want to simply connect to Event Bus to send/publish/receive messages, and is fairly easy to achieve.

I did it for a Grails (SB-based) project and put the Vertx stuff inside a `service` like:

```
class VertxService {
  Vertx vertx

  @PostConstruct
  void init() {
    def options = [:]
    Vertx.clusteredVertx(options){ res ->
      if (res.succeeded())
        vertx = res.result()
       else
        System.exit( -1 )
    })
  }

  void publish( addr, msg ){ vertx.publish addr, msg }

  //...
}
```